# How can I use dotenv with vite/petite vue?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, environment-variables

How can I use `.env` variable in `petite-vue` project?
when run `yarn vite` it give me error: `process is not defined`

The file structure is this:

```
Root
|_index.html
|_vue-index.ts
```

I've imported vue script in `index.html` and with something like `console.log('Hello')` connected to a button work fine so it's not a problem of importing script.
But, when I try to `console.log(process.env.URL)` it returns me that error and @click don't do nothing.

```sh
# .env
URL=http://example.com
```

```js
// vue-index.ts
import { createApp } from 'petite-vue';
import 'dotenv/config';

createApp({
  print() {
   console.log(process.env.API_URL);
  },
}).mount('#app');
```

The problems seems to be in `import.meta.env.` things by vite.
MY problem was that with TS that things is not permitted without changing `tsconfig.json` moule options to `esnext` or other.

Someone that can explain me how to use it?
If I run this with `ts-node` work properly.

```js
import 'dotenv/config'

console.log(processs.env.API_URL)
```

Comment: `import 'dotenv/config'` runs in node and doesn't affect the way the app works in browser. There's no `process` in browser.  This won't happen automatically, Vue CLI does some work to expose `process.env`. I didn't check in vite but it's likely https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html

Answer (score 6):

1- Create `.env` file in your home directory. It is **not** in the `/src` folder.

2- Only keys starting with **`VITE_`** can be accessed in the `.env` file from within **Vite + Vue 3**.

Example `.env` file content

```
VITE_BACKEND_PORT = 5000
VITE_MAP_KEY = eae5454ii5557772142
BACKEND_PORT = itIsInaccessible
```

Example of using in `App.vue` file

```
<script setup>
const backendPort = import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_PORT;
const mapKey = import.meta.env.VITE_MAP_KEY;
console.log(backendPort)
console.log(mapKey)
</script>
<template>
{{backendPort}} {{mapKey}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

For whoever come's here looking to solve the problem I've found that the most simple way of doing it is with [this](https://github.com/ElMassimo/vite-plugin-environment) plugin.

Just add this few line to vite.config.*

```js
// vite.config.ts
import EnvironmentPlugin from 'vite-plugin-environment'; // Here we import the plugin that expose env variable when vite bundle up the app

const config = {
  root: './src',

  // Here you can define which env to expose with prefix params
  // i.e.: EnvironmentPlugin('all', {prefix: 'test'}) => test_env_var == true, env_var == false
  plugins: [EnvironmentPlugin('all', {prefix: ''})], 
};

export default config;
```

Comment: presumably you still need an .env file and do you use import.meta.env,variablename rather than process.env ?